# Transitioning Audio Unit code to ARC

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting, core-audio

Apologies if this is too vague... this is my first post here and I'm well and truly stumped on this issue!

I've been attempting to transition an iOS Xcode project using Audio Units to ARC, but it appears to have broken the functionality of the audio unit processing class. Some symptoms... When I attempt referencing 'self' in AUProcessor.mm, the AUProcessor class is referred to as 'const*', whereas in the pre-ARC version, there was no 'const*' mentioned.

This pointer to 'self' produces the following error:

`callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;`

`[error] Assigning to 'void *' from incompatible type 'AUProcessor *const __strong'.`

I can remove the error by adding (__bridge void*) ahead of self, which allows the project to compile. However, the Audio Unit processor doesn't work in the app.

I can't see anything elsewhere in the code that is significantly different from the pre-ARC version in terms of how the class is referenced.

Let me know if more context is required.

Thanks in advance!!

(BTW, thank you to all contributors to these forums... they are truly a wonderful resource for keen yet inexperienced programmers!)

Answer (score 9):

Typically, `(__bridge void*)` would be the correct cast here. This means "take a pointer to this object without applying any memory management; I promise I'll hold onto it for as long as it's needed." (That last part is just implied, but if you don't, you'll crash.)

Are you certain that `self` continues to exist for as long as this audio unit? If nothing has a strong reference to `self`, then it will disappear and `inputProcRefCon` will become a dangling pointer.

When you say "doesn't work in the app," what do you mean? Does it crash? Does the callback not happen? When the callback happens, does it not have the right data?

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far Rob. The app is based on the pitchDetector tutorial from http://sleepyleaf.com/. The AUProcessor (RIOInterface) class contains multiple methods for initiating and analyzing an audio stream, such as FFT to determine pitch. The class then returns values which are displayed on screen. After my attempted ARC transition, the audio stream and eveyrthing else associated with the class doesn't seem to correctly initiate. No audio buffers come through, etc, until I attempt to stop the audio stream, when the app crashes.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this helped me to make the SpeakHere example ARC compatible. I feel like I've been here before, too, but then I would've left a comment, so I guess not ;)  +1

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve my issue by excluding the troublesome class from ARC using the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc`.

Its not a very satisfying conclusion but at least my app is working again... Looks like I'm going to need to learn more about memory management!

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working for me with the MusicPlayer API. I don't **know** that it is correct but I am not getting any errors or memory leaks. Hope it helps!

// assign the callback:

```
 MusicSequenceSetUserCallback( sequence, MyEventCallback, (__bridge_retained void *)self );
```

//the callback method:

```
void  MyEventCallback(void                      *inClientData,
                  MusicSequence             inSequence,
                  MusicTrack                    inTrack,
                  MusicTimeStamp                inEventTime,
                  const MusicEventUserData  *inEventData,
                  MusicTimeStamp                inStartSliceBeat,
                  MusicTimeStamp                inEndSliceBeat)
{

struct MyMusicEventUserData* userEventData = ( MyMusicEventUserData *)inEventData;

[(__bridge MusicPlayerController*)inClientData MIDIEvent:userEventData 
                                               eventTime:inEventTime 
                                          startSliceBeat:inStartSliceBeat 
                                            endSliceBeat:inEndSliceBeat];
}
```

Comment: This is over-retaining `self`, which will cause it to leak. Using `__bridge_retained` here transfers ownership of `self` to the `void*` (i.e. adds +1 retain). You never balance that with a release, so the object is leaked. That this works, though, suggests that nothing else in the system has a strong pointer to this object, which is more likely your problem. You generally shouldn't ask the AU system to hold it for you, but if you do, you need to make sure to release it when the AU system is done with it.

Comment: Really? I have a `UIViewController` which holds a `strong` reference to `MusicPlayerController` (i.e. `self` above). Perhaps I am not seeing any issues because both the `UIViewController` + `MusicPlayerController` persist for the entire lifespan of the app? I'll try `(__bridge void*)`

Comment: Over-retains will not leak any object that has the same lifetime as the entire app.